# Resistor values for adjustable voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, schematics, datasheet

I'm using a [LT1529 voltage regulator](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1529fb.pdf) and I'm having a hard time understanding the process for determining the resistors to use in the voltage divider.  The datasheet provides the following schematic and calculation:

[image: LT1529 Adj Version Schematic]

> ADJ (Pin 2): Adjust Pin. For the LT1529 (adjustable
>   version) the ADJ pin is the input to the error amplifier. This
>   pin is internally clamped to 6V and – 0.6V (one VBE). This
>   pin has a bias current of 150nA which flows into the pin.
>   See Bias Current curve in the Typical Performance Characteristics.
>   The ADJ pin reference voltage is equal to 3.75V
>   referenced to ground.

I want an output voltage of 4.0V.  The typical ADJ pin bias current (which I think is the desired current for the adj pin) is 150nA.  I'm not sure if I should use these values to determine the R2 resistor.  It gives a rather large resistance value (like 26.6M).  Once I know R2, R1 should be easy to solve for but I would appreciate confirmation on that value too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turn the problem around: Once you know **R1**, then R2 is easy to solve for. R1 is pretty easy to decide upon.

It is a bit of a balancing act, really, but here's how it goes:

- The datasheet suggests R1 be kept **below 400 kOhms** for stability. Lower the value of R1, higher the quiescent current required by the voltage splitter R1+R2. Higher the value of R1, higher the instability of the output.
- We know that the upper leg of R1 in the diagram is biased at 3.75 Volts for steady state.
- Hence, let us start with the maximum standard E12 series resistor value for R1 within the datasheet constraints, i.e. **390 KOhms**
- I<sub>R1</sub> can be calculated thus: `I = V / R = 3.75 / 390,000 = 9.61538 uA`
- Current through R2 is given as the sum of current through R1, and bias current 150 nA. I<sub>R2</sub> is thus `9.61538 - 0.15 = 9.46538 nA`
- For a desired output voltage of 4.0 Volts, R2 must thus develop `4.0 - 3.75 = 0.25 Volts` for the above current.
- Therefore `R2 = 0.25 / 9.46538e-6 = 26412 Ohms`. Closest E12 value = **27 kOhms**.
- Vo with R1 = 390 k and R2 = 27 k is **4.01367 Volts**, less than 0.5% deviation from target voltage (assuming perfect resistor values, of course).

If stability is more desirable than saving quiescent current, try the above sequence with a starting value of R1 as **22 kOhms**.

- I<sub>R1</sub> = 170.455 uA
- I<sub>R2</sub> = 170.305 uA
- R2 = 1468 Ohms, nearest E12 value **1.5 kOhms**
- Vo = **4.00591 Volts**.

Using the above calculation steps, choose any value for R1 as long as it is less than 400 kOhms, to obtain the value of R2.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need.  Thank you.  One other question while I have your attention.  Do you have any suggestions for the value of the capacitor?  I suppose it depends on my load?

Comment: The minimum recommended value is 22µF with an ESR of 0.2Ω or less, says the datasheet. Start with that value, increase it if ripple is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet seems to be clear.  See Fig 2 (pg 8) and the equation under this figure shows that it's a standard non-inverting amplifier gain equation.  If you pick a value for R1, say 100k, the equation can be re-written as 100K(Vout/3.75 - 1) = R2.  They suggest making R1<400k to minimize errors due to the bias current, that's why I picked 100k.